# Excel VBA Sentence Case Function

Tags: excel, vba

I found an old post regarding a sentence case function at the following link. 
  [Converting to sentence case using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978560/converting-to-sentence-case-using-vba?answertab=active#tab-top)

I happen to love the following function designed by bretdj

```
Function ProperCaps(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strIn = LCase$(strIn)
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .ignoreCase = True
     .Pattern = "(^|[\.\?\!\r\t]\s?)([a-z])"
    If .test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        For Each objRegM In objRegMC
            Mid$(strIn, objRegM.firstindex + 1, objRegM.Length) = UCase$(objRegM)
        Next
    End If
    MsgBox strIn
End With
```

What i can't figure out is how to make the function to sentence case the string typed in a particular cell and then put the corrected sentence back into the original cell.  I don't need it in a message box. Something similar to the following:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, myrange2) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Value = ProperCaps(Target.Value)
End If
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Forgive me for reposting this, I'm not authorized to comment on posts.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: If you comment out the `MsgBox strIn` line in the `ProperCaps()` function, does it not do what you want? What does it do?

Comment: No, it clears the value in the cell whether {MsgBox strIn} is there or not.  I want to correct the string using ProperCaps and then put it back into that cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is missing the last part, but if the last part is just one more line `End Function` then all you need to do is replace `MsgBox strIn` with `ProperCaps = strIn`:

---

```
Option Explicit

Function ProperCaps(strIn As String) As String

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegMC As Object
    Dim objRegM As Object

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    strIn = LCase$(strIn)

    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .ignoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(^|[\.\?\!\r\t]\s?)([a-z])"

        If .test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)

            For Each objRegM In objRegMC
                Mid$(strIn, objRegM.firstindex + 1, objRegM.Length) = UCase$(objRegM)
            Next
        End If
    End With

    ProperCaps = strIn

End Function
```

Comment: One simple line that I couldn't figure out.  You solved my problem.  Thanks Paul

Comment: One quick question, I'm not familiar with this code so I don't understand it.  How do I tweak it to capitalize the first letter of the first word?

Comment: Can you show me the text where the first letter doesn't get capitalized (I just need to see a few characters preceding the capitalized letter)

Comment: This was entered as all lower case in the same large cell.  Each additional line after the first one is entered using Alt+Enter.
"the academy will include one day of training
for county chief execs.  A total of three and
one half days.  Each county can send up to 
two individuals.  They may include the 
county exec."

Comment: So the only one that should be capitalized is the first "t" in "the"?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  In doing some more testing, if i enter a sentence in all caps, the text remains all caps.  I thought that the code puts everything to all lcase then capitalizes the appropriate letters.  Am I wrong?

Comment: I think I found the issue: please open a new question and I'll provide a solution (still testing it) and more details related to it

Comment: Paul, I posted a new and related question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167519/excel-vba-sentence-case-funtion-needs-fine-tuning