# Excel VBA Sentence Case Funtion Needs Fine Tuning

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a function built by others that changes text into sentence case (first letter of each sentence capitalized).  The function works nicely except it doesn't capitalize the first letter of the first word.  Another issue is that if a sentence is entered in all caps, the function does nothing.  I'm looking for some assistance in tweaking the function to correct these issues.

```
Option Explicit 
Function ProperCaps(strIn As String) As String

Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
strIn = LCase$(strIn)

With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .ignoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "(^|[\.\?\!\r\t]\s?)([a-z])"

    If .test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)

        For Each objRegM In objRegMC
            Mid$(strIn, objRegM.firstindex + 1, objRegM.Length) = UCase$(objRegM)
        Next
    End If
End With

ProperCaps = strIn
End Function
```

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: This statement from you seems contradictory:  "The function works nicely except it doesn't capitalize the first letter of the first word."  Isn't "capitalize the first letter of the first word" the same as "first letter of each sentence capitalized"?  How can it work nicely if it fails to perform it's intended fundamental operation?

Comment: Ok, it does have some flaws and I'm looking for assistance in correcting it. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the function to SentenceCase() and made a few more adjustments:

---

```
Public Function SentenceCase(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim regEx As Object, regExM As Object, indx As Object, indxs As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    str = Replace$(str, vbNullChar, vbLf)
    str = Replace$(str, vbBack, vbLf)
    str = LTrim$(LCase$(str))
    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(^|[\n\f\r\t\v\.\!\?]\s*)(\w)"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set indxs = .Execute(str)
            For Each indx In indxs
                Mid$(str, indx.FirstIndex + 1, indx.Length) = UCase$(indx)
            Next
        End If
    End With
    SentenceCase = str
End Function
```

---

This is what I tested it with:

```
MsgBox SentenceCase(" UPPER CASE SENTENCE." & _
                    vbCrLf & "next line!nEXT sENTENCE" & _
                    vbCr & "cr ! lower case" & _
                    vbLf & "lf .new sentence" & _
                    vbNullChar & " null?null char" & _
                    vbNullString & "nullString  spaces" & _
                    vbTab & "TAB CHAR.ttt" & _
                    vbBack & "back?  back char" & _
                    vbFormFeed & "ff  ff words" & _
                    vbVerticalTab & "vertical tab.| lower .case words")
```

Results:

[image: test 1]

[image: test 2]

[image: test 3]

You can find more details here: [Microsoft - Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

Comment: Paul it still does not capitalize the first letter of the first sentence.

Comment: i did some testing and came up with another issue.  Your new code capitalizes the first letter of the first sentence but only in a message box not in the cell itself.  Your new code also capitalizes the first letter of each line whether it is the beginning of a sentence or not.

Comment: I used the following to capitalize the first letter of the first sentence. {If myrange2.Value <> "" Then
       For Each myrange2 In Target
            myrange2.Value = UCase(Left(myrange2.Value, 1)) & Mid(myrange2.Value, 2)
       Next
    End If}

Comment: I'll test it with ranges, but I have a quick question: a new line is not a new sentence? Can you upload a screen shot highlighting the issue(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Paul thank you  for taking the time to help.  I gave up and searched the net some more found a workable sub, received help from another bulletin board and came up with the following:

```
Sub SentenceCase(rng As Range) 
Dim V       As Variant 
Dim s       As String 
Dim Start   As Boolean 
Dim i       As Long 
Dim ch      As String 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
ActiveSheet.Unprotect 

With rng 
    V = .Value 
    If IsDate(V) Or IsNumeric(V) Then Exit Sub 
    s = CStr(V) 
    Start = True 

    For i = 1 To Len(s) 
        ch = Mid$(s, i, 1) 
        Select Case ch 
        Case "." 
            Start = True 
        Case "?" 
            Start = True 
        Case "!" 
            Start = True 
        Case "a" To "z" 
            If Start Then ch = UCase$(ch) 
            Start = False 
        Case "A" To "Z" 
            If Start Then 
                Start = False 
            Else 
                ch = LCase$(ch) 
            End If 
        End Select 
        Mid$(s, i, 1) = ch 
    Next i 
    .Value = s 
End With 

ActiveSheet.Protect 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

This code is doing what I needed.  Again thank you for your help.

Gary