# Concatenate cells in a range to a string per row first

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I want to make a sentence in a new cell (I23), with all cells values in the range J2:S2 if they are not empty.

This is my board :

[image]

It should mark a sentence like : "in this morning I have oui, aaaaaah, nooooo, yeeees, 225, maybe, y, y"

But the pb is that number of value can change (you see it in the second row)

this is my code for now :

```
y = Sum("J2:S2")
     For Z = 1 To Z = y
     If Range("J2:S2") <> " " Then
     Cells(Z, 2) = Range("J2:S2")
     End If
     Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon here. Something that would probably work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub J2S2()

    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim strResult       As String

    For Each rngCell In Range("J2:S2")
        If Len(rngCell) Then
            strResult = strResult & " " & rngCell
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Debug.Print Trim(strResult & ".")

End Sub
```

It prints all values of the cells in the range `J2:S2` to the immediate window. Separated with a space. I have added a full stop at the end, as far as you mentioned the output should be a sentence.

If you want to make it sentece case, here is a good example: [Converting to sentence case using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978560/converting-to-sentence-case-using-vba)

**Edit:** 
Alternatively, if you want to loop through columns first, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColumnsFirstJ2S4()

    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim strResult       As String

    Dim lngRow          As Long
    Dim lngCol          As Long

    Dim rngTarget       As Range

    Set rngTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("J2:S4")

    With rngTarget

    For lngCol = .Column To .Columns.Count + .Column
        For lngRow = .Row To .Rows.Count + .Row

                If Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)) Then
                    strResult = strResult & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)
                End If

        Next lngRow
    Next lngCol

    End With

    Debug.Print "ADDING TEXT here " & Trim(strResult & ".")
    ActiveSheet.Range("I23") = "ADDING TEXT here " & Trim(strResult & ".")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Vityata ! Your code is great and he help me a lot ! But i have still somes problems, your code write row by row, is it possible to write column by column ? and if I want to write it in a cells, i cant do Range("I23").value = Debug.Print Trim(strResult & "."). And if I want to add text in front of ?

Comment: It write it well in a cells but still row by row :(

Comment: @babou - try again. I have changed the for loops.